# `[!]` (exclamation mark in brackets) wildcard in bash

Tags: command-line, bash

I have came across globbing patterns and wildcards and of particular interest to me is `[!]`.

> This construct is similar to the `[!]` construct, except rather than matching any characters inside the brackets, it'll match any character, as long as it is not listed between the `[` and `]`.

```
rm myfile [!192]
```

The above I believe will remove any/all files, except for any/all files which have 192 in their name.

I am concerned however about the proper usage of this with a file extension, and in particular multiple conditions.

What would be the proper syntax in such a situation?

```
rm myfile [!.gif .csv. mp3]
```

or

```
rm myfile [!.gif !.csv !.mp3]
```

My worry is that the period might be misplaced, and so **any** file with a `.` (which would be any of them surely?) would then be manipulated, when I am seeking to cause manipulation of specific files.

This construct is similar to the `[ ]` construct, except rather than matching any characters inside the brackets, it'll match any character, as long as it is not listed between the `[` and `]`.

(quoted from http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm)

Now; to me that suggests then a singular `!` is sufficient, and all values therein after are contained within the range.

Comment: as a general tip, use `ls my-pattern` or `echo my-command` to check if the globbing is done the way you want, before running `rm`

Comment: Also, remember that many, if not most, files don't have extensions. Extensions on Linux systems are usually irrelevant and are not used to define the file type by the majority of programs.

Comment: Note that your first quote is misquoted, now it seems to basically say that `[!]` is similar but not like `[!]`

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `^` has the exact same meaning as `!` in this context, therefore `[^a]` excludes `a` exactly like `[!a]` does: *If the first character following the [ is a !  or a ^ then any character not enclosed is matched.* (`man bash`)

Comment: `rm myfile [!192]` will remove `myfile`, as well as any single-character file not named `1`, `9`, or `2`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Citing [`man 7 glob`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/glob.7.html):

```
An  expression  "[!...]"  matches  a single character, namely any character
that is not matched by the expression obtained by removing the first '!' from it.
(Thus, "[!]a-]" matches any single character except ']', 'a' and '-'.)
```

Emphasis on the **single character** part here, `[]` can not be used for whole strings in Bash Pattern Matching.

---

`bash`'s [Brace Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) can be used to match strings, however there is no way (I know of) to negate them. E.g.

```bash
1.{gif,csv,mp3}
```

is expanded to

```bash
1.gif 1.csv 1.mp3
```

no matter whether these files exist.

---

As [wchargin](https://askubuntu.com/users/20219/wchargin) pointed out `shopt` can be used to enable extended pattern matching operators, one of them being `!()`. After running `shopt -s extglob`, e.g.

```bash
1.!(gif|csv|mp3)
```

is expanded to

```bash
1.jpg 1.bmp 1.png
```

if those files exist in the current directory. For more read [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc13) (section EXPANSION/Pathname Expansion) and [Pathname expansion (globbing)](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs).

---

For what you're trying to do I'd always use `find`, which offers the negation and much more, e.g. in the following way:

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "*.gif" -a ! -name "*.csv" -a ! -name "*.mp3"
```

This just lists the findings, if you want to remove them just append the `-delete` option **to the end** of the command. As always with removing actions: **Always check carefully first**.

`find` offers a ton of useful options very well explained by [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/find.1.html).

Comment: Note that this `find` command is recursive (*edit: as it was originally shown* - I might keep this comment for the additional relevant but nonessential info it conveys). To find files residing only in the current directory but not also its subdirectories--and thus only delete those files if the `-delete` action is added--you can add `-maxdepth 1` immediately after `find .`. This would bring it in line with the effect of globbing, as globs are nonrecursive in Bash unless the `globstar` shell option is turned on and `**` is used. The glob shown in the question is nonrecursive in all shells.

Answer (score 10):

I think you misunderstood the use of brackets. `[abc]` matches **one** of the characters `a`, `b` or `c`. `[!abc]` matches **one** character that is *not* `a`, `b` or `c`. So the commmand

```bash
rm myfile [192]
```

will remove `myfile` and the files `1`, `9` and `2` because you have a space between myfile and the bracket. In contrast, the command

```bash
rm myfile[192]
```

will remove the files `myfile1`, `myfile9` and `myfile2`.

Comment: true.  Better to use `find`.

Comment: Actually [] is used for a range, [!] a single character

Comment: @IronUhlan, they both take a range or a list of characters. It's just that the other is a negation.

Answer (score 7):

Brackets `[` `]` denote a character class. Any single character inside them may match in the given position. So

```
file[192]
```

matches three possible names:

```
file1
file2
file9
```

It does *not* match `file192`, because it only deals with the single character after `file`.

We can also use ranges in brackets. `[0-9]` matches any single digit in the given position. For two digits, we need `[0-9][0-9]`. For a digit followed by a capital letter, we could use `[0-9][A-Z]`...

`!` indicates negation.

```
file[!192]
```

will match files that have any single character after `file` except `1` or `9` or `2`. For example it will match `file7` and `files` and `file%` (and many others) but *not* `file192`, because that has two extra characters.

For your use case, I suggest using `find` instead of `[!]`. It has a `not` operator.

It's also *recursive*, which means it goes into all subdirectories by default. You can limit it to the current directory with `-maxdepth 1`, if that's what you want. Shell wildcards (globbing) is non-recursive (although recursive globbing with `**` can be enabled).

Assuming you don't want to avoid deleting symlinks, we can add `-type d` to the negated tests to avoid deleting any directories. Thanks to Eliah Kagan for that suggestion.

```
find /path -maxdepth 1 -not \( -type d -or -iname "*.gif" -or -iname "*.csv" -or -iname "*.mp3" \)
```

If you see what you want, you can run the command again with `-delete`

```
find /path -maxdepth 1  -not \( -type d -or -iname "*.gif" -or -iname "*.csv" -or -iname "*.mp3" \) -delete
```

Comment: And I think you can also do several ranges at once. For example, hexadecimal digit could be `[0-9a-fA-F]`

Comment: @Zanna, yes! I was actually using find :) Didn't realise it had a "not" operator :)