# How can I combine file listings using sed?

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I wish to list the files of a few folders, in reverse alphabetical order, and then aggregate that data into a single file (`AllDirectoriesFileInfo.txt`). I've already figured out the sorting; now it is merely collating the info that is stumping me. Here is what I have so far:

```
ls -r /home/tony/Desktop/jpgfolder > AllDirectoriesFileInfo.txt
ls -r /home/tony/Desktop/giffolder > AllDirectoriesFileInfo.txt
ls -r /home/tony/Desktop/docxfolder > AllDirectoriesFileInfo.txt
ls -r /home/tony/Desktop/dregsfolder > AllDirectoriesFileInfo.txt
```

However, upon inspection of `AllDirectoriesFileInfo.txt`, only the information from `dregsfolder` is present, leading me to conclude that the previous data has been overwritten with each command.

So, I am aware that `sed` can add/insert text.

Initially I was leaning towards using `a`;

> The syntax is as simple, simply designate the line after which a new line is to be inserted by using its corresponding number or a pattern.

However for me, specifying a line number is problematic. Say I specify line 50, will there be a massive desert of white space? Or say a larger file is utilised, then does the information become garbled?

I am aware that with the `i` command (insert) the user is able to specify the point at which new text is inserted.

My thinking, and pseudocode is as follows:

```
All information of folder 1 stored here
**END of folder 1 info**
All information of folder 2 stored here
```

And then from there, use SED to insert the next file after END of folder 1 info

Would this work? Or am I barking at the moon here?

Comment: BTW, `sed` does support appending to a file using `sed '$a'`, but I can't figure out how to make it work in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're barking at the moon. Just use the append redirector `>>` instead of the write redirector `>`:

```
touch AllDirectoriesFileInfo.txt
ls -r /home/tony/Desktop/jpgfolder >> AllDirectoriesFileInfo.txt
ls -r /home/tony/Desktop/giffolder >> AllDirectoriesFileInfo.txt
ls -r /home/tony/Desktop/docxfolder >> AllDirectoriesFileInfo.txt
ls -r /home/tony/Desktop/dregsfolder >> AllDirectoriesFileInfo.txt
```

Or forget about appending, and just give `ls` multiple arguments:

```
ls -r /home/tony/Desktop/jpgfolder /home/tony/Desktop/giffolder /home/tony/Desktop/docxfolder /home/tony/Desktop/dregsfolder >> AllDirectoriesFileInfo.txt
```

Simplified:

```
ls -r ~tony/Desktop/{jpgfolder,giffolder,docxfolder,dregsfolder} >> AllDirectoriesFileInfo.txt
```

Even shorter, assuming `tony` is your username:

```
ls -r ~/Desktop/{jpg,gif,docx,dregs}folder >> AllDirectoriesFileInfo.txt
```

---

Although, if you're going to be doing any processing on the data in the file, you'll want to use `find` instead of `ls`, since in general, `ls` gives output for humans to read, and `find` gives output for computers to read. Specifically in this case, `find` lists the file *and* its path together.

Here's a quick example:

```
$ mkdir dir1 dir2
$ touch {dir1,dir2}/file1
$ ls -r dir1 dir2 > ls_r_out.txt
```

Now say I want to search for "file1":

```
$ grep 'file1$' ls_r_out.txt
file1
file1
```

OK, that's not very helpful, cause it doesn't tell me *where* the files are. I'll try the same process with `find`. Now, `find` doesn't support sorting, so I'll have to pipe through `sort`:

```
$ find dir1 dir2 | sort -r > find_reverse_out.txt
$ grep 'file1$' find_reverse_out.txt 
dir2/file1
dir1/file1
```

Voila. Note that this gets more complicated if the filenames contain any special characters like newlines.

Comment: Verbosity is a sin best kept for Java. THANK YOU.

Edit: you mention that find should be used in lieu of ls (in the event of processing). Could you give an example please?

Comment: NP. Sure, I'll add an example now.

Comment: +1 You'll want to use `find` exactly like in all of the other closely related questions you asked since yesterday: https://askubuntu.com/questions/974735/moving-files-of-specific-type-extension-from-one-directory-to-another, https://askubuntu.com/questions/974979/exclamation-mark-in-brackets-wildcard-in-bash and https://askubuntu.com/questions/975111/find-paths-must-precede-expression-xargs.